# Implementing three-pass-protocol in C# using RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to implement the [Three-Pass Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-pass_protocol) in C# using RSA. However, this requires the encryption in question to be commutative, and I don't know whether or not RSA is.

Furthermore, it requires (at least as far as I can tell) the encryption used to be able to encrypt its own cyphertext with a key of the same length as the encryption, which RSA doesn't seem to be able to do (I tried and got a CryptographicException "Bad Length.")

Does anyone have any helpful hints or ideas?

Comment: The Wikipedia article does not say that you need a public-key algorithm like RSA. To me its sounds like any symmetric-key algorithm works where the encryption and decryption function have this property regarding commutativity.

Comment: @dtb Ah, you have a point. Do you know if AES is commutative?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if it is or not. I would search for some official specification of a  three-pass protocol (e.g., from NIST or  IETF) that tells you exactly what to do and what algorithms to use. Inventing your own crypto mechanism based on a Wikipedia article will lead to disaster.

Comment: AES is not commutative. Paddingless RSA is. Only a few specific mathematical structures are both secure and commutative. I doubt you'll find any official spec, since three-pass seems to pretty useless. Why use it over plain RSA?

Comment: This is indeed an algorithm that is not used in practice. But for toying around all you need is a large prime for which DL (and probably also DH) is hard. And doing modular exponentiation in C# is of course easy using the method ModPow from system.numberics.BigInteger.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I know this is old, but I'm curious. It is theoretically possible that in some circumstance you have limited messages and don't want to request/retrieve public keys. How significant is the disadvantage in using a commutative encryption scheme?